# Lock down Virtual Box

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, powershell, administrator, sudo

We have pc-labs for students in our Windows AD environment with virtualbox installed and couple of virtual machines.

Our goal is to provide shrotcuts for a prebuilt predefined virtual machines, and totaly disable regular user to change vm or create new one.

Virtual Box have only options to lock down GUI [Locking down Vbox Gui](https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/guitweaks.html)

And lot of other options that can do the work - only problem that regular user can edit xml config file that lands in `%USERPROFILE%\.VirtualBox\` folder. He can unlock all Gui restrictions as if they never existed.

I trying to do the following:

```
 1. Create local service account - vbx
 2. Create shortcuts for vms 
 3. Change ownership of all related to Virtual Box folders to be owned by vbx 
 4. When student clicks on shortcut  I use Start-Process from powershell
    to start the vm on behalf of vbx user loading its creadentials from file.


e.g. $credential=Get-Credential
     $credential | Export-Clixml -Path '.\vbxpass.xml'
```

Now I'm at the point of "chicken and egg" problem - simply because now user can inspect my script and modify it to access xml config file.

Question: How to lock down Virtual Box?
How to store service account credentials securely?
May be there is a better way to solving this problem?

Thank You.

Comment: Is the student a local admin? If not, then you can set the config file to read-only once it's created or remove/deny write access for the user, even if it's in their user profile directory.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Yes, we thought about it. If You put read/write restrictions on config file Virtual Box will not run.  Because of that I create another user that will own all files that Virtual Box needs. For now I also trying to set up a scheduled task triggered by event id. When student taps on icon powershell writes to event log special id e.g. 55511 and task triggered. But another problem VM start with no GUI and inaccessible to student.

Comment: Yes the student has to run virtualbox themselves, or the gui won't display in their session. If you need the gui, then your options are going to be very limited. You can use the VirtualBox web service or something like RemoteBox to have users access the virtualbox server (running as other user) "remotely", and give users a specific set of permissions that they can't change.

Comment: not sure if I fully understand your issue - could you just make the virtual hard disk 'read-only'? Then, whatever users do, all writing goes to a delta-disk, and and you can 'reset' the VirtualBox with a click whenever you want to?

Comment: @Aganju It will fail Virtual Box will not start if something is read-only. It stated in docs. We want to secure machine settings - network settings, disk settings, global settings. Then it will be secure to run vm like "Kali Linux" in Your network. For now creating service with FileSystemWatcher seems to be a solution. Virtual Box, neither VMWare, neither Hyper-V do not have this capabilities built-in.

Comment: I don't mean the file-system read-only, but VirtualBox has a special mode for that. Check the docu under 5.4 "Immutable Images" (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#hdimagewrites).

Comment: @Aganju Thank You for clarification, didn't knew about this feature... But it will not help because what we want is 1 . vms without access to our local network 2. that student would not be able in any way change it. If we apply immutable images one can easily revert it by using VBoxManage utility. For now the reasonable solution seams to be a service that will monitor files for changes and via Windows Event Forwarding report to admin or logoff user, or just restoring those files silently while killing Virtual Box  process. I think You got the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It stands out that You can put read-only restrictions on `VirtualBox.xml` config file, but if one of those restrictions will be `noSelector` e.g.
`VBoxManage setextradata global GUI/Customizations noSelector,noMenuBar,noStatusBar`

You won't be able to start VM from GUI only via shorcut (or cli - `VBoxManage startvm`). So to restrict regular user to:

1. Modify existing VM settings
2. Create new VM with its own settings

We done the following:

1. First create and set all VMs as regular.
2. Create shortcuts (right click -> create shortcut on Desktop)
3. Run VboxManage restirction commands
4. Put read-only restrictions for `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users` or another group that fit Your needs on all files that You want to protect. Main config file, .vbox file inside machine folder etc.. But notice that Users should have **"Modify, Synchronize"** permissions on Log folders inside VM folders.

That's it now You can launch VM via shorcut, but cannot nor modify configurations neither create new virtual machines as regular user.